# SQL: Sort Results of a Query Based on the Order of values from another Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

Suppose I have a table with 3 columns:

- YEAR
- COMPANY
- DEPARTMENT
- SALES

And I wanted to display the following:

- COMPANY
- DEPARTMENT
- SUM(SALES)

The additional requirement being that the COMPANY with the Maximum Sales (across all departments) shows first, and the rest of the results ordered accordingly.

How would I go about writing my query?

I've tried the following, and it doesn't work:

```
SELECT t1.company,
   cs1.deparment, 
   SUM(cs1.sales) 
FROM   company_sales cs1, 
   (SELECT cs2.company, 
                   SUM(cs2.sales) 
            FROM   company_sales cs2
            WHERE  cs2.company IS NOT NULL 
            GROUP  BY cs2.company 
            ORDER  BY 2 DESC) t1
WHERE  cs1.company = t1.company 
GROUP  BY t1.company,  
      cs1.deparment;
```

Comment: BTW, I'm trying this in PostgreSQL.

Comment: select company,department,sum(sales) from table group by company,department    order by company

Comment: @ivan, there is more to the requirement than just grouping and ordering at one level. Please refer to my question again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using window functions:

```
select company, department, sum(sales)
from t
group by company, department
order by sum(sum(sales)) over (partition by company) desc, company;
```

You can also include the expression in the `select` clause to see the sum of sales for the entire company.

Comment: Worked like a Charm !! Thanks for the solution.

Comment: you require a second condition in that order by clause i.e. `, department`

Comment: @Used_By_Already . . . Actually, it does need a second condition -- `company` -- to handle ties.  I'm not sure what subsequent keys should be.

Comment: `the rest of the results ordered accordingly.` is very unclear but suggests it needs both company (as tie breaker) and department after that. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 SELECT company,department,sum(sales) 
 FROM table GROUP BY company,department 
 ORDER BY Max(sales)
```

Comment: Anton, this won't work for me, as I'm looking at Sales of a Company across all departments, not just one department.